# Unread by Owner field on a custom object - Any workarounds?

Tags: formula, custom-field, view

Is there a way I can create a custom field in my custom object which can tell if that record is read/viewed or not ? (without having to Edit the record). Thank you!

Comment: One way to achieve that could be by adding a VF section on the record's detail page that updates the read/viewed field no page load.